# audiobooks syncing problem

Tags: audiobook

I've downloaded audiobooks from OverDrive Media Console to my computer with no problem. When I sync my Iphone 4 to my computer, the book chapters don't sync in chronological order: what can I do to have the chapters sync identically to the order I have on Itunes, instead of erratic order I get on Iphone?